# Getting specific values in a TreeMap

Tags: java, treemap

So, I have grabbed what I believe Treemap as a String which looks like this:

```
{Username1={password=password1}, Username2={password=password2}}
```

How would I go about getting the values 'Username' and 'Username2' As well as Username1's Password(password1) and Username2's Password(password2)? Is there a way to iterate over those values in an array or something like that?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this in Java? If so please add the relevant tag by editing your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TreeMap` is an ordered `Map`. All maps have those 3 methods:

```
map.keySet(); //returns a Set containing the keys (Username in your case)
map.values(); //returns a Collection containing the values (the passwords in your case)
map.entrySet(); //retrurns a Set of entries (an entry is a key + value)
```

If you want to access both in a loop, the best way is through the entryset:

```
for (Map.Entry<UserName, Password> e : map.entrySet()) {
    UserName user = e.getKey();
    Password pwd = e.getValue();
}
```

Comment: How would I iterate over each value?

Comment: @DuncanPalmer Let me know if that does not answer your question.

Comment: How do I assign the Key and Value paramaters in Map.Entry<K,V>

Comment: Don't you have access to the map in itself? Only to its string representation?

Comment: I can get the Object value of it.

Comment: If you receive an object and you know it's a map, you can cast it like this: `Map<UserName, Password> map = (Map<UserName, Password>) mapAsAnObject;`. If the object is not some kind of `Map<UserName, Password>`, you will receive a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: It's giving me errors at the 'UserName' and 'Password" paramters.

Comment: Isn't it probably a `Map<String, String>` ?

Comment: @DuncanPalmer Without giving more information about where you get the map from it can only be a guess.

Comment: @beerbajay Username could well be a string, but I don't think password is a string (the output of map.toString would just show username=password if it were the case).

Comment: Apparently the value of the password value is TreeMap, when I tried getting the string value I recieved the error: java.util.TreeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: The object may be a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` then.